# How to remove spaces between cells in a html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-spacing

I try to remove white space between Table1Header and Table2Header. I tried border:0px, padding:0px and border-spacing:0px; styles. Firefox and Opera tell me that my border-spacing style is overrided by the user agent style (which is 2px). How can I force browser to use my styleshits?

http://jsfiddle.net/cdjDR/2/

```
<table class="tableGroup">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="tableHeader">
                            <td><span class="tableHeader"><label>Table1Header</label></span>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=" tableData">
                            <td>
                                <div class="ui-datatable">
                                    <div>
                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div><span><span class="ui-header-text">Table1Col1</span></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><span>2</span>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="tableHeader">
                            <td><span class="tableHeader"><label>Table2Header</label></span>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableData">
                            <td>
                                <div class="ui-datatable">
                                    <div>
                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div><span><span class="ui-header-text" >Table2Col1</span></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><span>12345</span>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

span.tableHeader > label {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    line-height:30px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 13px;
}
tr.tableHeader {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
table.tableGroup, table.tableGroup > tr > td > table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table.tableGroup div.ui-datatable th > div > span >span.ui-header-text {
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 11px;
}
table.tableGroup td, table.tableGroup th {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` is probably what you need. But, nevertheless -1 for this mess (even if it is just a sample)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers are not telling you that your `border-spacing` style is overridden by the user agent style sheet. Instead, they may indicate that *inheritance does not take place* for it. This is simply caused by the fact that *some* style sheet sets the property on the element.

The reason why your rule is not applied to the inner `table` element is that it does not match any of your selectors. The selector

```
table.tableGroup > tr > td > table
```

does not match it, because a `tr` element is never a child of `table` even if might appear to be. By HTML syntax, there is an intervening `tbody` element, even if its start and end tag are missing. The following selector would match:

```
table.tableGroup > tbody > tr > td > table
```

Of course, a mere `table` selector would do the job as well, provided that you want all `table` elements to be styled by the rule.

Comment: It's better if he uses `table.tableGroup table` if he is trying to collapse border of all the nested tables... or even better just `table {}` but anyways +1, I didn't told him that `tbody` was missed

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use `border-collapse: collapse;` or even `border-spacing: 0;` is fine

```
table { /* Will apply to all tables */
    border-spacing: 0;
    /* OR border-collapse: collapse; */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdjDR/4/)

You can easily override the useragent stylesheet with a simple element selector.

---

If you want to normalize the styles, you should use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

---

Coming to your selector which is seems dirty to me, as yo are targeting the table with `class` `.tableGroup` and the `table` nested under that

```
table.tableGroup, table.tableGroup > tr > td > table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

So you better use

```
table.tableGroup, 
table.tableGroup table {
   border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3193136 yes, but if you are targeting all the tables than don't use that selector

Answer (score 4):

you need to add (border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0") Table tributes in every table tag

**example**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

**example with your classes **

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="tableGroup">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
table {
    border-spacing:0px; 
}
```

[works by using css](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/cdjDR/6/)

Comment: tnx man .. not experienced as u.. trying learn from Stackoverflow as much as i can.. Your answer is much better than mine.. i also learn that i can also do that. Thanks ..

Comment: No hard feelings :) we answer wrong and we learn, just do this with CSS, I will upvote your answer :)