# Space Between Table Cell

Tags: html, css

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8XX5m/) and let me know why there are lines between the cells in the table while there is no border setting?

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By default there is a 'border setting'. That's why you should use `cellspacing=0` in the `table` tag.

Comment: Possible dublicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108708/how-to-remove-spaces-between-cells-in-a-html-table

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

To collapse the borders

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XX5m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The default browser style add a padding of one pixel on table cells tags.

To avoid default browser css you can use a css file like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can also remove all borders in your table by using the border-spacing or border-collapse property on your table tag.

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

or

```
table {
    border-collapse: 0;
}
```

Comment: The default padding is specifically on table cells, not “tags” in general. “CSS reset” is a blunt instrument at best and a source of confusion at worst.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<table style="width:300px" cellspacing="0">
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XX5m/2/)

Comment: I'm not the one who voted it down, but usually it's considered best practice to keep view-related things out of HTML and store it in CSS, so that HTML acts as kind of hierarchical container only. In your case, `cellspacing="0"` is related to view and could be changed to `border-spacing: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The lines are caused by spacing between cells. It is empty space, which means that normally the background of the table (here, green) shines thru. This spacing is often described as “border spacing”, since it can be seen as spacing between logical borders. If no border has been set, like here, the borders still logically exist, though as zero width. For two adjacent cells, we thus have the setup

...[cell1 content] [right padding] [right border] [border spacing] [left border of cell2] [left padding of cell1] [cell1 content]...

So although it may look like a border, it is really spacing between (invisible) borders.

There are several ways to remove it:

1. Use the HTML attribute `cellspacing=0` on the `table` element. This is supported by all browsers that render tables normally. Nominally, the attribute is deprecated in HTML 4, obsolete and nonconforming in HTML5, but browsers are still expected to keep supporting it.
2. Use `table { border-spacing: 0 }`, which corresponds to the HTML attribute. Browser support is good, but still more limited than for the other methods. This method lets you set nonzero border spacing for borders between *rows*, e.g. `table {border-spacing: 0 2px}`.
3. Use `table { border-collapse: collapse }`, which has very good browser support. It causes the collapsing border model to be used, with possible side effects. It makes the borders (possibly virtual, zero-width borders) of adjacent cells to coincide, so there cannot be any border spacing between them.